# Delete rows with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I want to delete all rows that start with "//", from Excel sheet, with PHPExcel.
My code:

```
require '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE);


$path = "del_head.xls";

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);


for($row=1; $row < $highestRow; ++$row){
   $value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();

   if (substr($value,0,2) == "//") {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row, $row);
      }
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
$objWriter->save($path);
```

But, the code not delete all rows that start with "//".
I think the problem is with function 'removeRow'.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Replace this line

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row, $row);
```

with

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's one obvious problem with your call to `removeRow()`: The first argument is the starting row, the second is the number of rows to remove; so if you find a // at row 5, then you're telling PHPExcel to remove 5 rows starting from row 5 (i.e. rows 5 to 9).

You're also reading a file with a .xls extension (assuming that it's a BIFF file from the extension), but saving with the same .xls filename as an OfficeOpenXML file (which is normally a .xlsx file).

So what format actually is your file? What does a call to the IOFactory's identify() method recognise it as? If it's actually a comma- or tab-separated value file (most likely to have a leading `//`), then you'd be better using PHP's `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` functions to process it to remove those lines.

Comment: My Excel sheet is like this://SDN_parameter_mapping   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:Depth</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_Temp</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_Sal</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_SIGT</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_O2</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_O2(%)</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_PO4</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_SiO4</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_NO2</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_NO3</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:WC_NH4</subject>   
//<subject>SDN:LOCAL:Chl_a</subject>   
//   
So, I want to delete first 14 rows.

Comment: That isn't an Excel format at all: I'm not exactly sure what it is; but you'd be better off just using fopen(), then fgets() to read each line in turn

Comment: Work fine with this code:$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(1,8);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(1,6);

Comment: Hi, When I use removeRow it works for me but adds empty rows at last, like if I add 10 rows from row 21 - 30 , it deletes but when I convert to pdf it gives me PDF with extra 10 rows at bottom

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Its worked me

```
$filename     = 'path/example.xls';
$objReader    = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel  = $objReader->load($filename);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$row_id  = 1; // deleted row id
$number_rows = 2; // number of rows count 
if ($objWorksheet != NULL) {
    if ($objWorksheet->removeRow($row_id, $number_rows)) {
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save($filename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the value assigned on line:

```
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
```

I've tested this code and the value is always 1